# findviewbyid not working. when using gettext and printing the result. It's not printing anything

Tags: android

Everything is in order. But when I use gettext and print the result it's not printing anything. please help. I think it's not detecting the edittext field. Am I missing something. Below is the code

activity_login.java

```
public class Activity_Login extends AppCompatActivity {

     EditText userEmail,userPassword;
     static String email;
     String password;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


         userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Login_email);
         userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Login_password);
          Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login_login);
          Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login_signUp);

          email = userEmail.getText().toString();
          password = userPassword.getText().toString();
          System.out.println("-*-*-*-Activity_login-*-*-*");
          System.out.println(email);
          System.out.println(password);
          System.out.println("-*-*-*-Activity_login-*-*-*");
```

activity_login.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_Login_email"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/et_Login_password"
    android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_Login_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="Password"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_Login_login"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/et_Login_email"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/et_Login_email"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: Can you give us some more context such as where this code is in your Activity? Post more of the code including the method it is in.

Comment: I have update as you asked

Comment: use  Log method instead of System.print. Example
Log.e ("email",email.getText().toString())

Comment: Try ˋLog.d(email)ˋ.

Comment: ummm... are you getting the text of your edittext  RIGHT after you initialize it? And you expect it to tell you what is it? Of course its returning nothing...

Comment: @DroiDev you beautiful human being you. Thanks that helped. I moved it into the OnClick method and it worked just fine

Comment: great. i also coded it below but sounds like you are good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the text, which EditText holds, in the onCreate method. This is the point when the activity gets initialised and created and at this time there is no possibility that EditText contains any text unless you hardcore it in the layout. Instead, you could create a button for example (login in your case I assume) which will perform your logic.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the issue. I moved the getText into the OnClick method and it worked as it should've

Comment: Great to hear. Could you accept the answer if it helped? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ginsbma.runningapps.MainActivity">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="press me"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In code

```
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
System.out.println(edit.getText().toString().trim());

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, edit.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        System.out.println(edit.getText().toString().trim());

    }
});
```

It will print out nothing at first. If you type anything into the edit text and then press the button, it will print out whatever you wrote plus toast it on the screen.

happy coding